# Horizontal BlackBerry menu

Tags: java, blackberry

I have Android code for making a menu.  Now I want to do the same for BlackBerry.

My Android code overrides [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html).onCreateOptionsMenu and uses a [MenuInflater](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuInflater.html) to create the menu items.

Comment: can u show android screen shot?

Answer (score 0):

The corollary to Activity.onCreateOptionsMenu is [Field](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Field.html).makeContextMenu().

There is no direct correlation for the MenuInflater object - you write all of the UI hierarchy directly in Java for BlackBerry apps.   So in this case, your makeContextMenu() method will need to create some [MenuItem](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/MenuItem.html) objects, and add them to the returned [ContextMenu](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/ContextMenu.html) object.